# Improve upper bound for double sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation, upper-lower-bounds

Let $0<x<1$.
Is it possible to find a reasonably good upper bound (depending explicitly on $x$) for the following expression?
$$T(x)=\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi(2i+1)x)}{(2i+1)(2j+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2]}$$
My guess is that we have $T(x)\leq x\cdot C$ for some constant $C$ and indeed, since $\sin(y) \leq y$ for $y\geq 0$, we have
\begin{align}T(x)&\leq \sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \frac{\pi(2i+1)x}{(2i+1)(2j+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2]} \\
&=x \underbrace{\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty \frac{\pi}{(2j+1)[(2i+1)^2+(2j+1)^2]}}_{=C}.
\end{align}
BUT since the argument of the sine depends on the summation variable $i$ which is getting arbitrarily big, this upper bound is rather bad.
Can anybody improve this?

Comment: Did you mean $i, k = 0$ instead of $i, j = 0$ in the summation?

Comment: An easy improvement to your bound would be to note that $|\sin(\pi(2i+1)x)| \leq 1$ so that $|T(x)| \leq C(1 \land |x|)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @VVejalla Thanks for spotting the typo! I have edited it.

Comment: @pg_star Good point. That's an improvement if I assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but notice that I have assumed $0<x<1$, so $1 \wedge |x| = x$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}T(x)/x$ is your $C$, so you won't get much more at least for small $x$. What kind of bound do you expect?

Comment: @Randi It's still an improvement because $\pi(2i+1)x>1$ for sufficiently large values of $i$, which is exactly why your current argument fails to produce any upper bound.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use the labels $m$ and $n$ for the indices in the sums to avoid confusion with the complex number $i\in\Bbb{C}$. And in the variable $\theta:=\pi x$ things look a bit nicer.
The first thing to note is that in the double infinite sum
$$T(x)=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2m+1)\theta)}{(2m+1)(2n+1)[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2]},$$
the numerator $\sin((2m+1)\theta)$ seems like the biggest problem. Fortunately it doesn't depend on $n$, and so it makes sense to first try to eliminate $n$ altogether. Separating the variables as much as possible yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x)&=&\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((2n+1)\theta)}{(2m+1)(2n+1)[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2]}\\
&=&\sum_{m\geq0}\left(\frac{\sin((2m+1)\theta)}{2m+1}
\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2]}\right),\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and this inner sum over $n$ has the partial fraction expansion
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n\geq0}&&\hspace{-10pt}\frac{1}{(2n+1)[(2m+1)^2+(2n+1)^2]}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2(2m+1)^2}\sum_{n\geq0}\left[\frac{2}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)+(2m+1)i}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)-(2m+1)i}\right]\\
&=&\frac{1}{4(2m+1)^2}\sum_{n\geq0}\left[\frac{2}{n+\tfrac12}-\frac{1}{(n+\tfrac12)+(m+\tfrac12)i}-\frac{1}{(n+\tfrac12)-(m+\tfrac12)i}\right].
\end{eqnarray*}
We can express this infinite series more consicely in terms of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n\geq0}&&\hspace{-10pt}\left[\frac{2}{n+\tfrac12}-\frac{1}{(n+\tfrac12)+(m+\tfrac12)i}-\frac{1}{(n+\tfrac12)-(m+\tfrac12)i}\right]\\
&=&-\left(2\psi(\tfrac12)-\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)-\psi(\tfrac12-(m+\tfrac12)i)\right)\\
&=&-2\left(\psi(\tfrac12)-\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)\right)\\
&=&4\ln(2)+2\gamma+2\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\gamma$ denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). See also the section on [evaluation of sums of rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Evaluation_of_sums_of_rational_functions) at the Wikipedia page on the digamma function for more details on the first step in the derivation above. This allows us to rewrite the original sum as
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(x)&=&\sum_{m\geq0}\left(\frac{\sin((2m+1)\theta)}{(2m+1)^3}
\left[\ln(2)+\frac{\gamma}{2}+\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{2}\right]\right)\\
&=&\left(\ln(2)+\frac{\gamma}{2}\right)\left(\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\sin((2m+1)\theta)}{(2m+1)^3}\right)+\frac12\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}\sin((2m+1)\theta).
\end{eqnarray*}
This first series is the Fourier series for $\tfrac{\pi}{8}\theta(\pi-\theta)$, so we have
$$T(x)=\frac{\pi}{16}\left(2\ln(2)+\gamma\right)\theta(\pi-\theta)+\frac12\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}\sin((2m+1)\theta).$$
So now it remains to determine an upper bound for the series
$$S(\theta):=\sum_{m\geq0}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}\sin((2m+1)\theta).$$
This seems unlikely to have any manageable closed form, and from this point forward estimates enter the picture. This means striking a balance between sharpness and computability of the estimates, and the amount of time and effort I'm willing to put in.

---

I don't know much about series such as $S(\theta)$, or whether there is any pattern to the values of $\sin((2m+1)\theta)$ as $m$ ranges over the nonnegative integers. What is certain though is that $0<\sin(\theta)<\theta$ and that
$$|\sin((2m+1)\theta)|\leq1
\qquad\text{ for }\quad m\geq1,$$
because $0<\theta<\pi$. Now define the constants
\begin{eqnarray*}
A&:=&\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+\tfrac12i)\approx-0.8681073626\ldots,\\
B&:=&\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}\approx0.03247625\ldots,
\end{eqnarray*}
so that
$$S(\theta)
\leq A\sin(\theta)
+\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}|\sin((2m+1)\theta)|
\leq A\sin(\theta)+B.$$
Putting everything together this yields
$$T(x)\leq\frac{\pi^3}{16}\left(2\ln(2)+\gamma\right)x(1-x)+\frac12\left(A\sin(\pi x)+B\right).$$
This 'first order' bound can of course be refined by computing more initial terms of the series for $S(\theta)$, leaving a smaller remainder term $B$. For example, taking the first three terms yields the 'third order' bound
$$T(x)\leq\frac{\pi^3}{16}\left(2\ln(2)+\gamma\right)x(1-x)
+\frac12\left(A_0\sin(\pi x)+A_1\sin(3\pi x)+A_2\sin(5\pi x)+B_3\right),$$
where
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_0&=&\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+\tfrac12i)
&\approx&-0.8681073626\ldots,\\
A_1&=&\frac{1}{3^3}\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+\tfrac32i)
&\approx&\hphantom{-}0.0142581155\ldots,\\
A_2&=&\frac{1}{5^3}\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+\tfrac52i)
&\approx&\hphantom{-}0.0072753399\ldots,\\
B_3&=&\sum_{m\geq3}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac12+(m+\tfrac12)i)}{(2m+1)^3}
&\approx&\hphantom{-}0.0109427956\ldots.
\end{eqnarray*}
Below are two plots comparing the upper bounds to the original function $T(x)$. The plot on the left shows $T(x)$ in blue, and the first order bound in purple; the third order bound is indistinguishable from $T(x)$ at this scale. The plot on the right shows the difference between the third order upper bound and $T(x)$. For comparison it also shows the constant term $-\tfrac12B_3$.

[image]

This shows that for the number of terms $A_m\sin((2m+1)\pi x)$ we have expanded, the constant term $\tfrac12B_3$ is quite tight (it seems we could decrease the constant term by about $0.0015$). It also shows that the difference is dominated by the next term $c\sin(7\pi x)$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Very impressive! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Mathcad calculated the following approximate graph of the function $T$.
[image]

In this approximation we had a range both for $i$ and $j$ from $0$ to $100$. This approximation should be very precise because the series for $T(x)$ should converge very quickly, because for the range both for $i$ and $j$ from $0$ to $10$ we obtained an almost coinciding graph. I expect this approach can provide a rigorous computer aided bound for $T(x)$.

The graph looks symmetric, which suggest that $T(1-x)=T(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. The graph suggest that $T(x)$ is a bit bigger than a quadratic function $4T\left(\tfrac12\right)x(1-x)$. The value $T\left(\tfrac12\right)$ calculated  with the range both for $i$ and $j$ from $0$ to $10000$ is $0.51254399898721\dots$.