# Evaluate alternating double series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does anybody have an idea on how to evaluate the following double series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{nm(n^2+m^2)}$$
Clearly this is a convergent series but I think it might be hard to find a closed expression for this.

Comment: Is there any relation to [this question asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579981), or is the similarity just a coincidence?

Comment: By "evaluate", do you mean finding a closed form or evaluating it numerically?

Comment: @joriki Yes, there is! I saw the similar question yesterday and then I somehow started thinking about this more symmetrical problem and how one could **find a closed form** for this expression. I don't think that this helps to answer the original question, that is why I opened a new post.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2578533/348034).

Comment: An approach similar to my answer in the linked question suggests a first step:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+m}}{nm(n^2+m^2)}
&=&\sum_{m=1}^\infty\left[\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n^2+m^2)}\right]\\
&=&2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(mi)-\operatorname{Re}\psi(\tfrac m2i)}{m^2}\\
&=&2\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi(mi)}{m^2}
-\frac12\sum_{m\geq1}\frac{\operatorname{Re}\psi((m-\tfrac12)i)}{(m-\tfrac12)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
A closed form for this seems unlikely, however.